# how to build this template using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

i'm trying like crazy to make this template using jquery, and i ask your help

image idea LINK - https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/786x400q90/913/JZKWrp.png

I have these 4 images on the top. For any image i have one text and a big image. When i click on this image a new text and picture will show up
I'm using Pure Framework, to the frontend

============= My Code - html ===================

```
<div class="pure-u-17-24">
    <p class="tituloGrupo">Grupo</p>
    <img src="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2.png" alt="Grupo Bignardi - Soluções em Papel" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>  
    <img src="assets/images/front/grupo/bignardi-papeis.png" alt="Bignardi Papéis" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
    <img src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia.png" alt="Jandaia" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
    <img src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia-atacado.png" alt="Jandaia - Atacado em Papelaria" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
    <?php
        $primeiroValor = 0;
    ?>
    @foreach ($grupo as $grupo)
        @if($primeiroValor==0)
            <div class="pure-g show">
                <div class="pure-u-17-24 textoEmpresa">
                    {{$grupo->texto}}
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-7-24">
                    <img src="assets/images/grupo/{{$grupo->imagem}}" alt="{{$grupo->titulo}}" class="imagemEmpresa pure-img"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                $primeiroValor = 1;
            ?>
            @else
                <div class="pure-g hide">
                    <div class="pure-u-17-24 textoEmpresa">
                        {{$grupo->texto}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="pure-u-7-24">
                        <img src="assets/images/grupo/{{$grupo->imagem}}" alt="{{$grupo->titulo}}" class="imagemEmpresa pure-img"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
            @endif
    @endforeach
```

=================== My Code - Jquery =================

```
$(function() {
    $('.imagensSelecionaveis').click(function(){
        var pureg = $(this).parent().find('.pure-g');   
            if(!pureg.hasClass('show')) {
                pureg.addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
                pureg.slideDown(function() {
                    pureg.addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
                });
            }
    });
});
```

nothing happens

Comment: You wanna something like tab click on first image first image related data will show?

Comment: there is no `class=imagensSelecionaveis` in markup, what is that supposed to be in your jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not linking the 4 images on the top with the content you are trying to display at the bottom. So, to fix your code, you need to:

- Assign an id or data-* info in the top images
- Assign an id to the content divs below
- On click, get the id and display content accordingly

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/s8ehet0a/1/)

It might be something like this:

```
<div class="pure-u-17-24">
<p class="tituloGrupo">Grupo</p>
<img data-id="0" src="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2.png" alt="Grupo Bignardi - Soluções em Papel" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>  
<img data-id="1" src="assets/images/front/grupo/bignardi-papeis.png" alt="Bignardi Papéis" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
<img data-id="2" src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia.png" alt="Jandaia" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
<img data-id="3" src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia-atacado.png" alt="Jandaia - Atacado em Papelaria" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
<?php
    $primeiroValor = 0;
?>
@foreach ($grupo as $grupo)
    @if($primeiroValor==0)
        <div id="content0" class="pure-g show">
            <div class="pure-u-17-24 textoEmpresa">
                {{$grupo->texto}}
            </div>
            <div class="pure-u-7-24">
                <img src="assets/images/grupo/{{$grupo->imagem}}" alt="{{$grupo->titulo}}" class="imagemEmpresa pure-img"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            $primeiroValor = 1;
        ?>
        @else
            <div class="pure-g hide">
                <div id="content{{$primeiroValor++}}" class="pure-u-17-24 textoEmpresa">
                    {{$grupo->texto}}
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-7-24">
                    <img src="assets/images/grupo/{{$grupo->imagem}}" alt="{{$grupo->titulo}}" class="imagemEmpresa pure-img"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
@endforeach
```

And jQuery like:

```
$(function() {
    $('.imagensSelecionaveis').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $('.pure-g').hide();
        $('#content'+id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Now, with your code, when i click, everything disappears.

Comment: I changed "id="content{{$primeiroValor++}}" to " <div class="pure-g hide">", and change "$('.pure-g').hide();" to "$('.show').hide();" the  second tab it works, but in the third, the previous content remains and the new one is shown.

Comment: i changed some informations. Man, i'm very very grateful.It works !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-17-24">
                    <p class="tituloGrupo">Grupo</p>
                    <img data-id="0" src="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2.png" alt="Grupo Bignardi - Soluções em Papel" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>          
                    <img data-id="1" src="assets/images/front/grupo/bignardi-papeis.png" alt="Bignardi Papéis" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
                    <img data-id="2" src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia.png" alt="Jandaia" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
                    <img data-id="3" src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia-atacado.png" alt="Jandaia - Atacado em Papelaria" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>

                    <?php
                        $primeiroValor = 0;
                    ?>
                        @foreach ($grupo as $grupo)
                            @if($primeiroValor==0)
                                <div id="content0" class="pure-g show empresasjavascript">
                                    <div class="pure-u-17-24 textoEmpresa">
                                        {{$grupo->texto}}
                                        <div class="pure-g-">
                                            <div class="pure-u-1 linkExterno">
                                                <a href="http://{{$grupo->link}}" target="_blank">PARA SABER MAIS, VISITE O WEBSITE DA {{$grupo->titulo}}</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pure-u-7-24">
                                        <img src="assets/images/grupo/{{$grupo->imagem}}" alt="{{$grupo->titulo}}" class="imagemEmpresa pure-img"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                    $primeiroValor = 1;
                                ?>
                            @else
                                <div id="content{{$primeiroValor++}}" class="pure-g hide empresasjavascript">
                                    <div  class="pure-u-17-24 textoEmpresa">
                                        {{$grupo->texto}}
                                        <div class="pure-g-">
                                            <div class="pure-u-1 linkExterno">
                                                <a href="http://{{$grupo->link}}" target="_blank">PARA SABER MAIS, VISITE O WEBSITE DA {{$grupo->titulo}}</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pure-u-7-24">
                                        <img src="assets/images/grupo/{{$grupo->imagem}}" alt="{{$grupo->titulo}}" class="imagemEmpresa pure-img"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach


                </div>
```

================= JS =======================

```
$('.imagensSelecionaveis').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");        
    $('.empresasjavascript').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    $('#content'+id).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
});
```